# PHP class: Global variable vs Accessbale varibales

Tags: php, class, variables

I have a doubt what is the difference between below class.

```
class Test {

    var $location;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->location = 'India';
    }
}


class Test {

    protected $location;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->location = 'India';
    }
}
```

Why we use var ? What is the purpose of using var as global here.??

Please clarify me.

Comment: Basically, it looks like it was deprecated for a while but now is just a synonym for "public"

Comment: *Note:  The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an E_STRICT warning.*  http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keyword` before variable name defines the `visibility` of the variable. It defines the `access` rights for the particular variable.

**var**

When using `var`, it will be publicly accessible through out your project same as `public`.

**protected**

When using `protected`, variable is only accessible for the classes which extends parent class for particular page only.

> Note: The PHP 4 method of declaring a variable with the var keyword is still supported for compatibility reasons (as a synonym for the public keyword). In PHP 5 before 5.1.3, its usage would generate an E_STRICT warning.

[Read More Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)